# Is there a simple way to recursively copy all symbolic links under a directory to another directory, preserving the structure?

Tags: rsync, symlink

I have a directory `~/tmp/foo/` that's populated with subdirectories, files, and symbolic links.

```
$ tree ~/tmp/foo/
tmp/foo/
├── eggs
│   ├── baz
│   │   └── link3.txt -> /home/me/file3.txt
│   └── link2.txt -> /home/me/file2.txt
├── hello.txt
├── link1.txt -> /home/me/file1.txt
└── spam
    ├── link4.txt -> /home/me/file4.txt
    └── link5.txt -> /home/me/file5.txt

3 directories, 6 files
```

I want to recursively copy all the symbolic links under `~/tmp/foo/` as files (as if I'd used `cp -rH`) to another (nonempty) directory `~/bar/`. Is there a simple way to do this?

I've tried the following:

```
find ~/tmp/foo/ -type l -print | rsync -avzL --files-from=- ~/tmp/foo/ ~/tmp/bar/
```

But this fails.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "as files" -- in the copied version, do you want symlinks, or files (as if you'd used `cp -rH`)?

Comment: Yes, I want files as if I'd used `cp -rH`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your find path is "." and relative to your rsync path because find includes the path prefix in the results. Also read the error messages of rsync it will warn you if you get it wrong with something like;

```
rsync: link_stat "/test/a/a/1/3.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir a b 
cd a
mkdir 1
echo 1 > 1/2.txt
ln -s 1/2.txt 1/3.txt
tree ../
../
├── a
│   └── 1
│       ├── 2.txt
│       └── 3.txt -> a/1/2.txt
└── b
```

then

```
find . -type l | rsync -av --files-from=- ./ ../b/
building file list ... done
./
1/
1/3.txt -> a/1/2.txt

sent 99 bytes  received 25 bytes  248.00 bytes/sec
total size is 9  speedup is 0.07
tree ../
../
├── a
│   └── 1
│       ├── 2.txt
│       └── 3.txt -> a/1/2.txt
└── b
    └── 1
        └── 3.txt -> a/1/2.txt

4 directories, 3 files
```

If by failed you mean the -L command ( changing a/1/2.txt to b/1/2.txt ) makes it not work then ... I'm not sure why that is, but I would work around it with `mount --bind --make-slave`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind copying the regular file foo/hello.txt, you can use:

```
$ cp -RLv ~/foo/ ~/bar/
```

The `-L` switch instructs `cp` to dereference all symbolic links found in the tree. It differs from `-H` switch, which instructs dereference of symbolic links from command line arguments only.

However, if you intend to copy the links and the symlinks exclusively, the only idea I have got was making your command line suggestion a little more complicated:

```
$ ( cd ~/tmp/foo/ ; find -mindepth 1 '(' -type l -o -type d ')' -print | cut -b 3- ) | rsync -avzL --files-from=- ~/tmp/foo/ ~/tmp/bar/
```

The idea is:

- The `find` parameters are modified to return symlinks and directories and to return paths one level down (so it does not return the '.' entry)
- The `--files-from=` rsync parameter requires relative paths. So I had to force the `find` command to run within the source directory, by using `( cd ~/tmp/foo ; find )`
- The `cut -b 3-` cuts the `./` prefix from the `find` output.